# Handling logs of bash script and comments in text file

Tags: bash, comments

I am trying to read a text file which has few commented starts with '#', my bash script should read the lines of the text file which doesn't start with '#'. 
Also im trying to capture the output of echo statements in both logs and to show it console window for the user understanding.

I have tried to use the below query for capturing logs and printing in console

exec 2>&1 1>>$logfile

For reading each line of the file and calling the function, i have declared an array and to eliminate lines which starts with '#' , i have used the below query.

```
declare -a cmd_array 
while read -r -a cmd_array | grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' 
do
  "${cmd_array[@]}" 
done < "$text_file"
```

Note : I need to eliminate the line starts with '#' and remaining lines to be read and place in array as declared.

```
Bash script 
***********

#! /bin/bash

Function_1()
{
now=$( date '+%Y%m%d%H%M' )
eval logfile="$1"_"$now".log
exec 2>&1 1>>$logfile     ### Capture echo output in log and printing in console 
#exec 3>&1 1>>$logfile 2>&1
echo " "
echo "############################"
echo "Function execution Begins"
echo "############################"
echo "Log file got created with file name as $1.log"
eval number=$1
eval  path=$2
echo "number= $number"
ls -lR $path >> temp.txt
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo " Above query executed."
        else
        echo "Query execution failed"
        fi
echo "############################"
echo "Function execution Ends"
echo "############################"
echo " "
}

text_file=$1
echo $text_file
declare -a cmd_array  ### declaring a array 
while read -r -a cmd_array | grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)'  ### Read each line in the file with doesnt starts with '#' & keep it in array
do
  "${cmd_array[@]}" 
done < "$text_file"


Text file 
*********
####################################    
#Test
#Line2
####################################
Function_1 '125' '' ''
Function_1 '123' '' ''
```

Comment: Try `... done < <( grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' "$text_file")`

Comment: @walter : tried the above command. But ended up with syntax issue.

Comment: `read -a` does not parse and remove quotes, it just includes them literally in the array elements. Is there any reason you aren't just executing the "text file" as a shell script (or `source`ing it)?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson : I dont want to remove any quotes, i just want to eliminate the line which starts with # symbol. I dont want to convert the text file as shell script and append sourcing my master script in it.

Comment: @user78873 What’s the exact error message you got when you tried Walter A’s suggestion?

Comment: @user78873:  This is the error i have got when i used the walter suggestion.      k2.sh: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
k2.sh: line 37: `done < <( grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' "$text_file")'

Comment: Are you sure that `#!/bin/bash` is the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider piping the grep output into the read:

```
declare -a cmd_array  ### declaring a array 
    ### Read each line in the file with doesnt starts with '#' & keep it in array
grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' < "$text_file" | while read -r -a cmd_array
do
  "${cmd_array[@]}" 
done
```

I'm not clear about the output/logging comment. If you need the output appended to a file, in addition to stdout/console), consider using the 'tee' (probably 'tee -a')

Comment: `grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' "$text_file"` without `<` works too.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the input file `inputfile`

```
echo a
Function_1 '125' '' ''
# skip me
Function_1 '123' '' ''
echo b
```

and wrote this script:

```
declare -a cmd_array  ### declaring a array
while read -r -a cmd_array
do
  echo "${cmd_array[@]}"
  "${cmd_array[@]}"
  echo
done < <(grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' inputfile)
```

For showing output in log and console, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145654/57293

As @GordonDavisson suggested in a comment, you get a simular result with

```
source inputfile
```

ignoring comments and empty lines, and calling functions, so I am not sure why you would want an array.  This command can be included in your master script, you do not need to modify the inputfile.

Another advantage of sourcing the input is the handling of multi-line input and `#` in strings:

```
Function_1 '123' 'this is the second parameter, the third will be on the next line' \
     'third parameter for the Function_1 call'
echo "This echo continues
on the next line."
echo "Don't delete # comments in a string"
Function_1 '124' 'Parameter with #, interesting!' ''
```

Comment: Solution provided in the link doesnt works for me.  
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145654/57293
Note: < < this symbol doesnt works for me

Comment: try `diff <(echo 1) <(echo 2)` on the commandline and in your script. Is your shebang correct (`which bash`) ?

Comment: Yes i am using Bash script only

Comment: Does the diff work both on commandline and in script? Maybe try a new script avoiding other possible errors.

Comment: In a script a get the error `syntax error near unexpected token`, when I delete the shebang. Perhaps a DOS file with a hidden `^M`, additional spaces. When you run `source yourscript` from the commandline, the shebang is ignored and the result should be equal to running from the commandline.

Comment: Im not able to understand your point on deleting the shebang.

Comment: The first line with `#!/bin/bash` is called the shebang.It is used for determing with shell must be used. When you don't have a shebang, the current shell is used. In my case without shebang I was using `sh` and got an error. You must figure out why the line in the script in interpreted by `sh`, not `bash`. I gave some hints, but don't know how to help you more. Good luck!

Comment: @user78873 Are you running the script with the `sh` command? If so, that overrides the bash shebang and (depending on your OS) disables some or all bash extensions to the basic shell syntax, including `<( )`. You should run scripts just with their path (including `./script` or `/path/to/script` if it's somewhere else), or just by name if the directory it's in is in your `$PATH`.